# Merge multiple cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

Basically I have 3 mat like this:

```
Mat descriptors1
Mat descriptors2
Mat descriptors3
```

Where each descriptors have been loaded like this:

```
extractor->compute( object, kp, descriptors );
```

How could I join in a single Mat all the descriptors (append one mat to the other) ?

Example:

```
Mat fullDesc = descriptors1 + descriptors2 + descriptors3;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not very effective, but short:

```
descriptors1.push_back(descriptors2);
descriptors1.push_back(descriptors3);
```

After that `descriptors1` will be a concatenation.

---

Also there is an undocumented function `vconcat`:

```
void vconcat(const Mat* src, size_t nsrc, OutputArray dst);
void vconcat(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst);
void vconcat(InputArrayOfArrays src, OutputArray dst);
```